# Subtract UniCase HashSets

Tags: rust

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
extern crate unicase;

use unicase::UniCase; 
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let a = UniCase("a".to_owned());
    let b = UniCase("b".to_owned());
    let s1: HashSet<UniCase<String>> = [a].iter().cloned().collect();
    let s2: HashSet<UniCase<String>> = [a, b].iter().cloned().collect();
    let s3 = s2 - s1; 
}
```

([Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=cc0fba4feaacc1ceaabbb4c4fd1802ed))

And get this error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `-` cannot be applied to type `std::collections::HashSet<unicase::UniCase<std::string::String>>`
```

As far as I can see, the requirement for `Sub` between `HashSets` is that the contained type implements `Eq + Hash + Clone`, which `UniCase` seems to do. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html), `Sub` is implemented for **references** to `HashMap`s:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T, S> Sub<&'b HashSet<T, S>> for &'a HashSet<T, S> 
    where T: Eq + Hash + Clone,
          S: BuildHasher + Default,
```

Taking explicit references works:

```
extern crate unicase;

use unicase::UniCase;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let a = UniCase("a".to_owned());
    let b = UniCase("b".to_owned());
    let s1: HashSet<_> = [a.clone()].iter().cloned().collect();
    let s2: HashSet<_> = [a, b].iter().cloned().collect();
    let s3 = &s2 - &s1;
    println!("{:?}", s3);
}
```

There's no need to specify the inner type of `s1` or `s2` but you do have to clone `a` as it's moved into the array.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would not have been able to spot that one on my own :) Do you know why Sub is implemented for references? More general?

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling the implementation of `sub` is just `self.difference(rhs).cloned().collect()` (just like your construction of `s1`/`s2`!), and `difference` takes references. Why that takes references, yeah, I'd assume it's for flexibility - having a reference is more common. You could always write your own little wrappers that used the by-value iterator if the memory savings seemed worth it.